# barra de rolagem altera ajuste de conteúdo

Tags: html, css, rolamento, css-hover

Olá, pessoal!

Quero que a barra de rolagem da minha div só apareça quando o hover for ativado e até ai tudo bem. O problema é que quando o a barra de rolagem aparece, o conteúdo da div é jogado pra o lado e eu não queria isso. Aqui está um exemplo do que acontece junto com uma parte do código:

https://jsfiddle.net/gabigbe/9rk2y7ms/27/

```css
div>span {
  color: var(--cor-branca);
  font-family: var(--fonte-light);
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 100%;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

h4>span {
  font-family: var(--fonte-regular);
  color: var(--cor-branca);
}

div>b {
  color: var(--cor-branca);
  font-family: var(--fonte-regular);
}

.grid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #a8a8a8;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 15px;
}

.filter {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  width: 95%;
}

.selected {
  border-color: var(--cor-amarelo) !important;
  color: var(--cor-amarelo) !important;
}


/*scrollbar*/

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
}


/*caminho*/

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #3d3d3d;
}


/*barrinha*/

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #666666;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: calc(100% - 5px);
}

.scroll:hover {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="row">
    <!--coluna 1-->

    <!--título do gráfico-->
    <div class="col grid text-center selected">
      <h4><span class="selected">NOME DO GRÁFICO</span></h4>

      <!--filtrar gráficos por datas-->

      <div class="filter justify-content-center align-content-center">
        <span> <b>FILTRAR DE</b> &nbsp; </span>
        <input type="date" class="form-control date" />
        <span> <b> &nbsp; ATÉ &nbsp;</b> </span>
        <input type="date" class="form-control date" />
      </div>

      <!--descrição dos gráficos-->

      <div>
        <span class="descriptons">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam congue orci a
              egestas vestibulum. Aliquam laoreet quis lacus vel pellentesque.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver esse problema?

Obs.: estou usando bootstrap também.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode diminuir o tamanho do containner quando a barra de rolagem não aparecer, e aumentar quando ela aparecer:

```
.scroll{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: calc(100% - 5px);
}
.scroll:hover{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}
```

O `5px` é o tamanho do scroll, se for mudar o tamanho dele, precisa alterar aqui também